# How wealthy are canonical inner models?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, infinite-combinatorics, inner-model-theory, inner-models

One of the way a person shows their wealth is by having many diamonds. The same can be said about models of $\sf ZFC$. We can add generic diamond sequences, while preserving the old ones, so in some sense, some models have more diamonds than others. And some have none at all.

Recall that a diamond sequence is a sequence $\langle A_\alpha\subseteq\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ such that $A_\alpha\subseteq\alpha$, and for any $A\subseteq\omega_1$, $\{\alpha\mid A\cap\alpha=A_\alpha\}$ is stationary.

Very very clearly, we can replace any one particular $A_\alpha$, in fact any countably many of them, and in fact any non-stationary set of them, and the sequence is still a diamond sequence. By that trivial observation alone, if there is one diamond sequence, there are $2^{\aleph_1}$ of them.

So the "plain counting argument" is the wrong one. But we can talk about equivalence up to a non-stationary set. That is, two sequence are equivalent, if they differ on a non-stationary set.

Okay, but maybe you can find a permutation of $\omega_1$ which maps stationary sets to stationary sets. And maybe that permutation is not the identity (mod. non-stationary, that is), so maybe that gives you a new sequence, where in fact you just moved that diamond from an earring to a necklace.

So it is unclear to me that agreeing on a club is the right notion here. But maybe it is.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a better notion of making diamond sequences distinct?
2. How wealthy are canonical inner models? In particular does $L$ have only one diamond sequence (up to a reasonable notion of equivalence)?

The reason to ask is that normally we argue that a canonical inner model has a diamond sequence by constructing said sequence from some fine structural properties of the model. But that gives us a very concrete sequence, which may hint at the relative poverty in which canonical inner models live.

Comment: I just want to clarify that diamonds in canonical inner models are ethical diamonds, i.e. diamonds that were not obtained by forcing.

Comment: I think that equivalence up to a club is still too strong (you still have $2^{\aleph_1}$ many such diamond sequences from one). Take $X \subseteq \omega_1$ and ask the diamond to guess some coding of the pair (A, X), where $A \subseteq \omega_1$. By taking the guess for the A-part, in ordinals in which we guessed the $X$ part correctly, we get a diamond sequence. For any $X$ you get a different diamond sequence and the non-trivial parts of those sequences can agree only on a bounded piece.

Comment: Well, I suspected that much. But then, what would be a good way to identify "essentially the same" diamonds?

Comment: Let's start with: Is there a candidate (forcing) model where there is some evidence that one should reasonably expect wealth?

Comment: @Andrés: Correct me if I'm wrong, but we can add a generic diamond sequence by forcing with its initial segments. Now iterate... Or take a side-by-side product, I suppose, for at least $\aleph_2$ different diamonds.

Comment: (Note that this is predicated on a notion of "distinct" that is satisfied by pairwise generic sequences.)

Comment: @Asaf I fear that we need to clarify the notion first before much can be said. I was hoping that wealth could be expected because of combinatorial consequences: in this model we can build this and that diamond sequences, the first gives us A, the second B, and "there does not seem to be a reasonable way" of getting B from the first or A from the second.

Comment: @Andrés: Indeed that was my thinking. It might be that somehow I'm wrong. Maybe any reasonable notion of sameness results in either "everything is equivalent" or "there is a maximal number of diamonds".

Comment: @Andrés: One way is naturally to consider the relative constructibility order on diamond sequences. But then trivially we get that $L$ admits one class. Maybe that's okay...

Comment: Since you asked about the situation in $L$, I'll conjecture that, for any "reasonable" notion of equivalence, $L$ will have $\aleph_2$ inequivalent diamond-sequences and that this should be provable by tweaking standard constructions of one diamond sequence in $L$. (Here "reasonable" is intended to mean something like "combinatorial" and to exclude relative constructibility.)

Comment: @Andreas: That's interesting, I can see why that would be true. Maybe someone has a suggestion of a reasonable notion of equivalence, and then we can settle this...

Comment: A $\diamondsuit$-sequence gives you an almost disjoint family of stationary subsets of $\omega_1$ in a natural way.    Does that family capture any essential information about the $\diamondsuit$ sequence?  Do you get any mileage out of declaring two $\diamondsuit$ sequences equivalent if those a.d. families generate the same ideal, for example?  Just random late night thoughts..

Comment: @Todd: I imagine that this family is somehow related to the "agree modulo permutations on a club"?

Comment: Another random thought.  Replace your diamond sequences by allowing countably guesses at each $\delta$ instead of one.  Then you can distinguish diamond sequences by whether or not they are "somewhere" a $\diamond^*$-sequence, that is, whether there is a stationary set $S$ where any set is guessed  "almost always".  Once you've got a $\diamondsuit^*(S)$ sequence, any run-of-the-mill single-guessing $\diamondsuit$ sequence on $S$ is built from it in some sense.  This would push towards $L$ having only a single type of $\diamondsuit$ sequence, built from the hierarchy in standard way.

Comment: @Todd: Aha, that's nice. Does that also satisfy the "generic is different" criteria, so that generic diamonds are different?